# Is using a nested let idiomatic when mixing side-effectful code with assignments?

Tags: clojure

I have some code need first insert into db and then query back from db. I could either use nested `let` as below:

```
 (let [sql "sql text"]
    (clojure.java.jdbc/insert! ...)
    (let [query-result (clojure.java.jdbc/query ...)]
      (some-code-using query-result)))
```

or use one `let` but use some dummy variable as below:

```
(let [sql "sql text"
      dummy (clojure.java.jdbc/insert! ...)
      query-result (clojure.java.jdbc/query ...)]
  (some-code-using query-result))
```

Which one is better and typical usage in clojure?

Comment: I think your question is really asking *Is a nested let a good way to mix in side effects in clojure?*.

Comment: As a side-note: it's tradition to use `_` for dummy values.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical name for the "dummy" variable is `_`, and will make it clear that you don't intend to use the result of that call. Using `_` is also easier to follow than nested `let` calls.

```
(let [sql "sql text"
      _ (clojure.java.jdbc/insert! ...)
      query-result (clojure.java.jdbc/query ...)]
  (some-code-using-query-request))
```

Comment: I don't totally agree that `_` is easier to follow than nested `let` expressions. They're both fine, and do the same thing; use your own judgment as to which is better in a particular context.

Comment: In general I like to see `let` used to prep/bind the symbols for some side-effect function like `insert!`, and then a nested `let` to hold the next set of transformations/bindings for the next step. Using `_` in a `let` for side-effects almost always feels like a temporary "I'll move this out later" hack. But sometimes it's super trivial and doesn't matter either way. `let` is useful to group similar things. Sometimes I nest `let`s just to signify different groupings even though it could've all fit in a single `let`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with nesting `let` forms, I would say the former of your examples is the most readable thanks to a clearer separation of intent.